# C mktime() printing issue

Tags: c, mktime, time.h

iam working on program which separates characters by meaning. Currently i got issue with function konverzia. It should add name of day (wed, thu, fri...) to date string, but it doesnt give a shit. Date have to look like this Wed 2012-02-01 Thanks for any ideas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

 void vstup (int i, char buffer[], int s, int c)
  {
        printf("\n Type text for analysis: \n ");    
        scanf ("%80s", buffer);      /* Read a string into buffer  */
  }
 void detekcia (int i, char buffer[], int s, int c, int z)
  {
         while(buffer[i] != '\0') {
            if(isalpha(buffer[i]))
                 s++;                /* Increment letter count     */
            if(isdigit(buffer[i++]))
                 c++;                /* Increment digit count      */
            if(ispunct(buffer[i++]))
                 z++;
                                  }
        if (s >= 1 && c >= 1)
          printf("\n word: %s \n", buffer);     /*kombinacia cisla a pismena*/
        if (s >= 1 && c == 0)
          printf("\n word: %s \n", buffer);     /*WORD*/
        if (s == 0 && c >= 1 && z == 0)
          prvocislo (i,buffer,s,c);             /*NUMBER*/
        if (s >= 0 && c >= 1 && z >= 1)
          datum (i,buffer,s,c,z);               /*DATE*/
 }
  int prvocislo (int i, char buffer[], int s, int c) /*prime number fun*/
  {
        int x,count=0;
        int k = atoi(buffer);

        for (x=2; x<=k/2;x++){
            if (k%x==0){
                count++;
                   break;
                }
        }
        if (count==0 && k!=1 && k!=0)
            printf("\n number: %d (prime)\n",k);
        else
            printf("\n number: %d",k);
  }
  int datum (int i, char buffer[], int s, int c, int z)
  {
        int q = 0;
        char d[2];
        char m[2];
        char r[4];

        if (buffer[4]=='-' && buffer[7]=='-')
           q++;                                                                                           
    if (q==1 && buffer[5]<='1')
           q++;
        if (q==2 && buffer[8]<='3')
           q++;
        if (q==3){
           q++;
           d[1]==buffer[9];
           d[0]==buffer[8];
           m[1]==buffer[6];
           m[0]==buffer[5];
           r[3]==buffer[3];
           r[2]==buffer[2];
           r[1]==buffer[1];
           r[0]==buffer[0];
                 }
        if (q==4)
           konverzia (d,m,r);
   }
   int konverzia (char d[], char m[], char r[])
  {
        int rr = atoi(r);
        int dd = atoi(d);
        int mm = atoi(m);
        int ret;
        struct tm info;
        char date[10];

        info.tm_year = rr - 1900;
        info.tm_mon = mm - 1;
        info.tm_mday = dd;
        info.tm_wday = dd;

        ret = mktime(&info);
        if (ret == -1){
        printf("time error");
                      }
        else{
           strftime(date, sizeof(date),"%c",&info);
           printf(date);
            }

        return(0);
  }
  int main() {

  char buffer[80];
  int i = 0;
  int s = 0; /*pismeno*/
  int c = 0; /*cislo*/
  int z = 0;
  vstup (i,buffer,s,c);
  detekcia (i,buffer,s,c,z);
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: "info.tm_wday" gives you 0-6 for Mon, Thu, ... - so go to google and look for "switch/case" and solve it.

Comment: Ten chars is not even enough to print a regular data like 2015-10-16, let alone one with a weekday. If you want to enforce a certain date format, you can construct it on your own instead of relying on the preferred format `%c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a particular format, you have to constructa custom format string. The possible entries are listed in the [documentation for `strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). The `%c` format that you use is just the preferred format of your locale.

There are some issues with your code:

- You shouldn't set `tm_wday` to the day of the month. `tm_wday` is an index of the weekday, starting with 0 for Sunday.
- You should initialise your `struct tm` to zero, so that fields that you don't assign don't have nonsense values.
- Your `date` buffer is too short. `strftime` guards against overflow, but the date will be truncated.
- Don't `printf` strings directly, use `printf("%s", str)` instead. In particular, the format string shouldn't be a string you don't control. For example, an unknown `%` sequence in `strftime` might not get converted and will falsely be interpreted as `printf` format without the correct argument. Some static analysis tools insist on using only string literals as format strings. Good practice, I think.

So:

```
int konverzia(const char d[], const char m[], const char r[])
{
    int rr = atoi(r);
    int dd = atoi(d);
    int mm = atoi(m);

    struct tm info = {0};

    info.tm_year = rr - 1900;
    info.tm_mon = mm - 1;
    info.tm_mday = dd;

    if (mktime(&info) == -1) {
        printf("time error\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        char date[20];

        strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%a %Y-%m-%d", &info);
        printf("%s\n", date);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, i really appreciate your help, but look what it did to output:::::::.....                                                                      Type text for analysis: 
 2001-11-11
**Tue -1-11-30**:................... and it doesnt matter which input i type, it is always giving this Tue date

Comment: I haven't looked much at your program outside the `konverzia` function and I have tested it with a few dates explicitly, like `konverzia("16", "10", "2015");` I suggest you check the strings that you pass in. Doing a few more tests, I see that `mktime` "normalises" bad input, so that 31 June is really 1 July. That means that you should add extra checks for validity instead of relying on `mktime` returning -1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! finally i found the mistake, and now it works great :)